# SVG в JPEG на Android

Tags: android, svg, обработка-изображений, jpeg

Знаете ли вы способ конвертировать **SVG**(векторное изображение) в **JPG/JPEG/PNG** (любой растровый формат) в режими оффлайн выполнения приложения на **android**?

Comment: Фактически нужен код (библиотека) для конвертации SVG в JPG на java(kotlin)

Comment: VectorDrawable может рисовать на canvas

Comment: @Style-7 вопрос немного в другом, мне необходимо сохранить SVG изображение в формате JPG

Comment: так рисуете на Canvas с Bitmap а потом сохраняете в JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VectorDrawable можно нарисовать на Canvas, Canvas можно сохранить как Bitmap, а Bitmap по сути растровое изображение.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Из Bitmap в PNG

```
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, someOutStream)
```

Еще есть вариант с SVG библиотеой под android https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android